# When using an adverb, do pronouns come before or after?

Tags: translation, conjugations

I am try to translate “only one you” (only one of you but do not know if would translate correct) using yuiitsu as only one, does anata come before after thank you!

Comment: What is the implication, 1) "Everyone is unique in this world" or 2) "Only you can do it" or 3) other?

Comment: everyone is unique in this world

Answer (score 4):

Here are some fundamental rules:

- An adverb cannot modify a (pro)noun. An adverb is for modifying a verb or an adjective. To modify a (pro)noun, you need **an adjective**.
- Japanese modifiers almost always come before the modified word.

Therefore, you have to pick an adjective to modify あなた (*anata*, "you"). Fortunately, 唯一 (*yuiitsu*, "sole/only") can work as an adjective by adding the linking particle の (*no*). This type of word is called a *no-adjective* in Japanese. It has to be placed **before** the modified noun.

So you can say:

> 唯一のあなた (in kanji and kana)
>   ゆいいつのあなた (in kana only)
>   yuiitsu no anata (in romaji)

This is understandable, but I think this concept is better conveyed with a phrase like たった一人の自分 (*tatta hitori no jibun*; たった = *tatta* = "only", 一人 = *hitori* = "one (person)", 自分 = *jibun* = "self").